# Nested while Loop in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, nested

I'm working on nested loop in my project. that requires a series of numbers such as given below:

```
Y:0
Z:1
Y:0
z:2
Y:0
Z:3

Y:1
Z:1
Y:1
Z:2
Y:1
Z:3

Y:2
Z:1
Y:2
Z:2
Y:2
Z:3
```

Here is my coding.

```
Dim y As Integer = 0
Dim z As Integer = 0
While y < 3
    While z < 4
        MessageBox.Show("Y: " & y)
        MessageBox.Show("Z: " & z)
        z = z + 1
    End While
    y = y + 1
End While
```

Unfortunately It outputs only:

```
Y:0
Z:1
Y:0
z:2
Y:0
Z:3
```

and it does not go further.

Comment: `z = z + 1` increases `z` inside the inner loop. When `z = 4`, the inner loop exits and never enters again since the `While z < 4` condition doesn't allow it. The `MessageBox()` is only called inside the inner loop, though, so you never *see* `y` increase. (Btw, why not print the values to the output/immediate window with `Console.WriteLine()` or `Debug.WriteLine()` instead of spawning a number of dialogs?). You may want two `for` loops instead, or reset `z`. Btw2, in your example, `z` starts from `1`, in your code it doesn't.

Comment: You need to reset `z` before "z" while loop to start it over for next `y`? What he said ^ :)

Comment: If you had bothered to debug your code then you'd have seen the issue for yourself. Any question posted without first debugging is a bad question. If you don't know how to debug using breakpoints, learn now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to move where you Dim your Z

```
Dim y As Integer = 0
While y < 3
    Dim z As Integer = 0
    While z < 4
        MessageBox.Show("Y: " & y)
        MessageBox.Show("Z: " & z)
        z = z + 1
    End While
    y = y + 1
End While
```

THe program does go further, it's just that the second and third iterations of the Y loop Z is already at 4, so even though the Y loop runs, the Z loop doesn't, and it doesn't hence print anything (because printing is only done inside the Z loop)

I'll leave the bit where Z outputs integers that are off-by-one as an exercise for the reader ;)